# GLFW window icon

Tags: lwjgl, glfw

I am working on an OpenGL project with LWJGL. I'm unable to load an icon for the window, as `glfwSetWindowIcon` requires a `GLFWImage.Buffer`. After a long time of scouring the internet, this is what I got:

```java
try {
    BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(new File("favicon.png"));
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write( originalImage, "png", baos );
    baos.flush();
    byte[] imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();
    ByteBuffer buF = ByteBuffer.wrap(imageInByte);
    GLFWImage.Buffer b = new GLFWImage.Buffer(buF);
    glfwSetWindowIcon(window, b);
} catch (IOException io){
    System.out.println("Could not load window icon!");
    System.out.println(io.toString());
}
```

The java runtime crashes with an output like this:

> # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
> # The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
> # See problematic frame for where to report the bug.

I haven't been able to find a method to do this that doesn't give this kind of error. The official GLFW documentation says to use a method that doesn't seem to exist in LWJGL.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is unwieldy; however, it works for me! :)
It's based on code in the lwjgl [events](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3/blob/master/modules/core/src/test/java/org/lwjgl/demo/glfw/Events.java) demo, but to use that I had to implement the demo [IOUtil](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3/blob/master/modules/core/src/test/java/org/lwjgl/demo/util/IOUtil.java). The code for setting the icon is this:

```java
ByteBuffer icon16;
ByteBuffer icon32;
try {
    icon16 = IOUtil.ioResourceToByteBuffer("src/hexsweeper/hex16.png", 2048);
    icon32 = IOUtil.ioResourceToByteBuffer("src/hexsweeper/hex32.png", 4096);
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}


IntBuffer w = memAllocInt(1);
IntBuffer h = memAllocInt(1);
IntBuffer comp = memAllocInt(1);

try (GLFWImage.Buffer icons = GLFWImage.malloc(2)) {
    ByteBuffer pixels16 = stbi_load_from_memory(icon16, w, h, comp, 4);
    icons
            .position(0)
            .width(w.get(0))
            .height(h.get(0))
            .pixels(pixels16);
    
    ByteBuffer pixels32 = stbi_load_from_memory(icon32, w, h, comp, 4);
    icons
            .position(1)
            .width(w.get(0))
            .height(h.get(0))
            .pixels(pixels32);
    
    icons.position(0);
    glfwSetWindowIcon(window, icons);
    
    stbi_image_free(pixels32);
    stbi_image_free(pixels16);
}
```

The imports are as follows:

```java
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;

import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWImage;

import static org.lwjgl.stb.STBImage.*;
import static org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.*;
```

And in another file (named IOUtil), I put the following code taken from the LWJGL demo:

```java
import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils;
        
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.Channels;
import java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel;
import java.nio.channels.SeekableByteChannel;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import static org.lwjgl.BufferUtils.*;

public final class IOUtil {
    
    private IOUtil() {
    }
    
    private static ByteBuffer resizeBuffer(ByteBuffer buffer, int newCapacity) {
        ByteBuffer newBuffer = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(newCapacity);
        buffer.flip();
        newBuffer.put(buffer);
        return newBuffer;
    }
    
    /**
     * Reads the specified resource and returns the raw data as a ByteBuffer.
     *
     * @param resource   the resource to read
     * @param bufferSize the initial buffer size
     *
     * @return the resource data
     *
     * @throws IOException if an IO error occurs
     */
    public static ByteBuffer ioResourceToByteBuffer(String resource, int bufferSize) throws IOException {
        ByteBuffer buffer;
        
        Path path = Paths.get(resource);
        if ( Files.isReadable(path) ) {
            try (SeekableByteChannel fc = Files.newByteChannel(path)) {
                buffer = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer((int)fc.size() + 1);
                while ( fc.read(buffer) != -1 ) ;
            }
        } else {
            try (
                    InputStream source = IOUtil.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(resource);
                    ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(source)
            ) {
                buffer = createByteBuffer(bufferSize);
                
                while ( true ) {
                    int bytes = rbc.read(buffer);
                    if ( bytes == -1 )
                        break;
                    if ( buffer.remaining() == 0 )
                        buffer = resizeBuffer(buffer, buffer.capacity() * 2);
                }
            }
        }
        
        buffer.flip();
        return buffer;
    }   
}
```

Replace the `"src/hexsweeper/hex16.png"` with however you get to your files, the `window` with your window, and you should be set. This worked for me, hope it works for everyone else!

Note: I didn't write the bulk of this code. It was made by the wonderfully helpful LWJGL contributors apostolos, Spasi, and kappaOne.

Since this answer was written, the LWJGL demos have been moved, restructured and updated. The new IOUtils class is found [here](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3-demos/blob/main/src/org/lwjgl/demo/util/IOUtils.java).

Answer (score 0):

These three lines are at fault:

```java
ImageIO.write( originalImage, "png", baos );
...
ByteBuffer buF = ByteBuffer.wrap(imageInByte);
GLFWImage.Buffer b = new GLFWImage.Buffer(buF);
```

`ImageIO.write(originalImage, "png", baos)`: You're telling ImageIO to write the contents of your image into the output stream in the PNG file format. This is not a bitmap, but an encoded PNG file in memory. GLFW expects an 8-bit RGBA image, not a PNG image.

`ByteBuffer buF = ByteBuffer.wrap(imageInByte)`;
Native libraries cannot work with Java heap data. `ByteBuffer.wrap` creates a heap byte buffer from an array; it is invalid to pass this to native functions with LWJGL. You need to create a direct buffer (`ByteBuffer.allocateDirect`, and copy the array's contents into this buffer.

`new GLFWImage.Buffer(buF)` is not how to initialize a `GLFWImage`. [That initializer](https://javadoc.lwjgl.org/org/lwjgl/glfw/GLFWImage.Buffer.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.nio.ByteBuffer)) creates a `GLFWimage` with the contents of an existing `GLFWimage` stored in the given buffer.
Instead, use this:

```java
try (final var images = GLFWImage.create(1)) {
    images.get(0).set(width, height, pixels);
    glfwSetWindowIcon(window, images);
}
```